# Python Error Iterating Over a cx_Oracle Result Set

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I have some code that iterates over a cx_oracle result set like so:

```
for row in out_cursor:
    #do stuff
    print row
```

out_cursor is a cx_oracle Cursor object. This code usually works, but sometimes I get an error like this:

```
for row in out_cursor:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.48752'
```

I think I am misunderstanding some fundamental concepts, because that error does not make sense to me. Why does row have to be an int? When that code works, the row that is printed is not an int, it's a list of lots of different data types.

I'm having a hard time researching this problem. I've looked all over but don't really know what to search for! I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious that one of you stack-overflow-ers can point out to me!

Comment: Edit the question to include the full error stack trace message.

Comment: @JohnGordon I left the full error message out because it is all my company's own python files, and won't mean anything to people reading this.

Comment: Without seeing the full trace, I don't know how to help further.  It seems like the error must be in your code somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in cx_Oracle-6.0b2, which is the version I was using.

https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/86

Upgrading to cx_Oracle-7 fixed the problem.